# What is the best way to get a property and value with a particular attribute?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Given this definition:

```
[UniqueId("Ident")]
public class MyClass : MyBase
{
    public int Ident{ get; }
}
```

What is the best way from the "MyBase" class to get the "UniqueId" attribute, find the matching property name and get the underlying value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't an abstract method / property in the base-class be more suitable?

```
public abstract int UniqueId {get;}
```

Via attributes, like so:

```
object GetUniqueId() // or int
{
    Type type = GetType();
    UniqueIdAttribute attrib = null;
    foreach(UniqueIdAttribute tmp in 
        type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UniqueIdAttribute), true))
    {
        attrib = tmp;
        break;
    }
    if (attrib == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    return type.GetProperty(attrib.PropertyName).GetValue(this, null);
    // perhaps cast here...         
}
```

Comment: Care to explain why? Anyway, I've updated my example to show via reflection

Comment: But I stress: reflection is best reserved for when there is no other route; I see no sensible reason why an abstract / virtual method isn't perfectly good here; it will be a lot quicker, too.

Comment: I would second the part about the abstract method/property (regardless of the unexplained response). Worst case, you could make it "public abstract object UniqueId" if "int" doesn't work.

Comment: or, indeed, protected if the outside world doesn't need to know about the details.

Comment: I rethought the scenario, and I took your advice and made it a virtual property.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand why you'd want that attribute on the class. Wouldn't it be more obvious to add it to the property, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [UniqueId]
    public int Ident{ get; }
}
```

You could access this value using something like

```
var identity = objectThatHasAnIdentity.GetId();
```

`GetId` could now be an extension method on `object` that implements a code similar to what Marc posted above